# CCScrollView with CCControlButton. How to control the touch area?

Tags: cocos2d-x, ccscrolllayer

I have CCScrollView with container with CCControlButtons, when the buttons scroll out of the visible CCScrollView area, They are also can be touched too. How can I control the area ?

Comment: CCScrollView has numerous issues like these. Even the scrollview doesn't scroll smoothly. Had the same issue and made the view in native table view :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My problems:
There is a scrollView with many buttons (items). Above it there are 2 function buttons (return, start).

1. When I scroll down item buttons overlie function buttons. When I swallow all touches above my scrollview I will lose my function buttons. So I have to find another solution.
2. When I start draging scroll view a item button is pressed. When I ended the button action will be execute. This is very annoying.

But there is the solution. I have created new CCControlButton. It checks whether was clicked outside scrollview or was dragged. The button is used for items buttons.

```
bool ControlButtonForScrolling::checkIfTouchIsInsideScrollView(CCTouch *pTouch)
{
    CCPoint touchLocation = pTouch->getLocation(); // Get the touch position
    touchLocation = _scrollView->getParent()->convertToNodeSpace(touchLocation);
    CCRect bBox=_scrollView->boundingBox();
    bool result = bBox.containsPoint(touchLocation);
    return result;
}

bool ControlButtonForScrolling::ccTouchBegan(CCTouch *pTouch, CCEvent *pEvent)
{
    bool isInside = this->checkIfTouchIsInsideScrollView(pTouch);
    if (isInside) {
        return CCControlButton::ccTouchBegan(pTouch, pEvent);
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

void ControlButtonForScrolling::ccTouchMoved(CCTouch *pTouch, CCEvent *pEvent)
{
    CCControlButton::ccTouchMoved(pTouch, pEvent);
    _scrollWasDragged = true; // information about dragging is stored to prevent sending action
}

void ControlButtonForScrolling::ccTouchEnded(CCTouch *pTouch, CCEvent *pEvent)
{
    // this method is a copy of CCControlButton::ccTouchEnded except lines with _scrollWasDragged
    m_eState = CCControlStateNormal;
    m_isPushed = false;
    setHighlighted(false);

    if (!_scrollWasDragged)
    {
        if (isTouchInside(pTouch))
        {
            sendActionsForControlEvents(CCControlEventTouchUpInside);
        }
        else
        {
            sendActionsForControlEvents(CCControlEventTouchUpOutside);
        }
    }
    _scrollWasDragged = false;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Inspired by Tomasz's answer, I created an alternative solution, also inheriting from `CCControlButton`:

```
bool ScrollableButton::isTouchInside(CCTouch *touch) {
  return !dragging && CCControlButton::isTouchInside(touch);
}

bool ScrollableButton::ccTouchBegan(CCTouch *touch, CCEvent *event) {
  dragging = false;
  return CCControlButton::ccTouchBegan(touch, event);
}

void ScrollableButton::ccTouchMoved(CCTouch *touch, CCEvent *event) {
  if (!dragging && ccpDistance(touch->getLocation(), touch->getStartLocation()) > 25) {
    dragging = true;
  }
  CCControlButton::ccTouchMoved(touch, event);
}

void ScrollableButton::ccTouchEnded(CCTouch *touch, CCEvent *event) {
  CCControlButton::ccTouchEnded(touch, event);
  dragging = false;
}

void ScrollableButton::ccTouchCancelled(CCTouch *touch, CCEvent *event) {
  CCControlButton::ccTouchCancelled(touch, event);
  dragging = false;
}
```

The secret sauce is the override of the `isTouchInside` function, which will return `false` even if the touch is inside, but was moved. This way, the button will also release its "zoomed" state as soon as you start scrolling.

It also adds a small tolerance factor, so if the touch moves just a little, it's still considered a "click". This factor is hardcoded at 25 in the example above.